# How to print on a non standard size paper with libreoffice writer

Tags: printing, libreoffice

I have an odt file with the size of 107*96mm. (I want to make flashcards, so I bought the non-standard sized paper,107*96mm).
I want to print the document onto the paper, but it seemed that there's not such an option called "custom paper size". So I left the "paper size" as A4.
The small paper was suck in and put out, but it remained black. It seemed that it was out of printed region.
I am using LibreOffice 7.4.2.3 40(Build:3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LO will automatically switch to "User" when you change the page size. Since you want to apply the style to multiple documents, i recommend to create a custom page style:

1. <kbd>F11</kbd> opens the Formatter Side bar
2. the fourth button from left gives access to the Page Styles:
   [image]
3. Create a new Page Style and assign a name;
4. switch to the second tab ("Page") and modify Width and Height according your needs; the "Format" entry will switch automaticalle from the initial standard format to "User":
   [image]